# CS1061 не получается привязть модель

Tags: xamarin

У меня есть модель UserData, мне нужно с помощью нее вывести данные на странице, но я получаю ошибку. Я добавил using EcoTracker.Models; но это не помогло

```
public partial class UserProfilePage : ContentPage
{
    public UserProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this.UserData;
    }

    private async void EditProfilePage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new EditUserProfilePage());
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> Ошибка    CS1061  "UserProfilePage" не содержит определения "UserData", и
> не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "UserData", принимающий
> тип "UserProfilePage" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно,
> пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).